# Sheet size and memory usage in excel

Tags: vba, memory, excel-2010

Each worksheet is getting to large memory wise, I found that if I copied the rows and columns that had data in them and put into a new sheet then deleted the old one and renamed the new one the same name I could shrink my workbook size by 1 to 3 megabytes, its not a memory problem exactly but my code seems to run quicker when the book is smaller. I downloaded a program that is sopposed to delete all unused cells but cannot get it to work.

```
    Sub Reset_LastCell()
    ' http://support.microsoft.com/default...&Product=xlw2K
       ' Save the lastcell and start there.
       Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim A As Integer

    For Each Sh In Worksheets
    A = A + 1
    If A >= 28 Then
    Sh.Activate
       Set lastcell = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
       ' Set the rowstep and column steps so that it can move toward
       ' cell A1.
       rowstep = -1
       colstep = -1
       ' Loop while it can still move.
       While (rowstep + colstep <> 0) And (lastcell.Address <> "$A$1")
          ' Test to see if the current column has any data in any
          ' cells.
          If Application _
                .CountA(Range(Cells(1, lastcell.Column), lastcell)) _
                > 0 Then colstep = 0  'If data then stop the stepping
             ' Test to see if the current row has any data in any cells.
             ' If data exists, stop row stepping.
             If Application _
                   .CountA(Range(Cells(lastcell.Row, 1), lastcell)) _
                   > 0 Then rowstep = 0
                ' Move the lastcell pointer to a new location.
                Set lastcell = lastcell.Offset(rowstep, colstep)
                ' Update the status bar with the new "actual" last cell
                ' location.
                Application.StatusBar = "Lastcell: " & lastcell.Address
       Wend
       ' Clear and delete the "unused" columns.
       With Range(Cells(1, lastcell.Column + 1), "IV65536")
          Application.StatusBar = "Deleting column range: " & _
             .Address
          .Clear
          .Delete
       End With
       ' Clear and delete the "unused" rows.
       With Rows(lastcell.Row + 1 & ":65536")
          Application.StatusBar = "Deleting Row Range: " & _
             .Address
          .Clear
          .Delete
       End With
       ' Select cell A1.
       ' Reset the status bar to the Microsoft Excel default.
       Application.StatusBar = False
       If A >= 35 Then Exit Sub
       Range("AI2").Select
     End If
     Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: I thought this worked 3 or 4 years ago but now it does nothing when I hit run.

Comment: Do you actually have more than 28 sheets in your workbook?

Comment: That was an old work book that it worked on. But yes that one did. I'm hoping this one maxes out at 16 or so.

Comment: Well, your code only works if you have more than 28 worksheets

Comment: I forgot that was in there it was so I did not have to run thru all the sheets just 28 thru 35 only way I could figure out how to not run the whole workbook, this routine takes a long time to run. Fixed that part and it crashed but at least it's a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very easy means of reducing the workbook size is to save the file as a `.xlsb`. All code and all functions continue to work exactely the same. The only limitation is that the workbook can no longer be opened by Libre Office and other open source spreadsheet applications.

I have found that it also helps to speed up calculations of formulas... it may help with code.

**UPDATE**
Your code works fine on my machine, the only thing I needed to do was add `Dim` to the code because i use `Option Explicit`. Add the following to your code at the top:

```
Dim lastcell As Range
Dim colstep As Long
Dim rowstep As Long
```

Comment: Already using that it cut it down to about half the size. I think it is the way that my code clears and copies sheets into each other that I'm activating to many cells that then get deleted but not deactivated in excels memory, Paste in 10,000 entries then remove duplicates and end up with 50 new entries.

Comment: Have you checked for conditional formats and data validation? These can substantially increase the size of a file and it's calculation speed and typically go unnoticed. I'm guessing that in your originaly sheet there is something there that isn't immediately visible that makes the file large.

Comment: When you paste, are you just pasting values

Comment: No big formulas on this spreadsheet and turned off the conditional formatting, also where I do not teed to get a result and running code calculation turned to manual, speed things up a lot, any way to find out what excel thinks is the last row last column. Also that code must have been written for an older version of excel I just noticed that the rows and columns don't match up with my version. Last but not least ow or where to check for data validation.

Comment: You seem to have a good grasp, so this is probably a silly question, but I assume `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` and the like are already implemented? And yes, the row number tells me it was written for Excel 2003 or earlier.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply been trying to figure this out and may have it, after cleaning sheet and deleting everything if I copied it into a new workbook it came in at 200k.  as soon as I ran my code it expanded to 2.5 meg or so  but I don't thinkj it was the code it was a match function  =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(AJ1,$H$1:$H$10000,0)),"","Found"),,,,,used to say =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(AJ1,H:H,0)),"","Found")  .......I think that was what was activating 1,000,000 rows down.